# I want to parse text from a compressed XML feed using awk

Tags: regex, parsing, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to parse `<title>` and `<description>` from the compressed XML feed at http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot. I am trying to do the following

```
curl --silent "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot" | awk '/\btitle\b(.*?)\bdescription\b/'
```

and `grep -E` etc., but I could not get the substrings I wanted. It always returns the entire XML as it's compressed and the data is in one line.

I was able to test my Regex string by running it in a text editor.

Appreciate your help!! Thank you!

Comment: "I want to parse [...] XML [...] using awk" - That's where you screwed it up.

Comment: in case you have to do it with awk, `but I could not get the substrings I wanted`, what do you want???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an XSLT solution:

```sh
curl -s -o- http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot | xsltproc slashdot.xsl -
```

where `slashdot.xsl` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:variable name="newline">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='//item' />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='//item'>
    <xsl:value-of select='title' /><xsl:value-of select='$newline' />
    <xsl:text>====</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select='$newline' />
    <xsl:value-of select='description' /><xsl:value-of select='$newline' />
    <xsl:value-of select='$newline' />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am setting this as the correct answer because it's very simple to understand, use and change to my needs.. I am using this in my geektool now, but special thanks to Birei for helping me out in the first place !!

Answer (score 1):

Using a XML parser would help, here a test with `perl` and `XML::Twig`. Adapt it to your needs.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'title' => \&extract_text,
        'description' => \&extract_text,
    },  
)->parsefile( shift );

sub extract_text {
    my ($t, $e) = @_; 
    printf qq|%s\n=================\n|, $e->tag;
    printf qq|%s\n\n|, $e->text;
}
```

Run it like:

```
curl --silent "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot" | perl script.pl -
```

That yiedls something like the following for each pair title and description:

```
title
=================
Proof-of-Concept Port of XBMC to SDL 2.0 and Wayland

description
=================
hypnosec wrote in with news that XBMC has  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Birei. I am new to Perl. I am facing issues related to XMLTwig while running the script.

Comment: mini:scripts balaji$ curl --silent 'http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot' | perl parserss.pl 
Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at parserss.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at parserss.pl line 3.
mini:scripts balaji$

Comment: @BalajiNatarajan: It seems you didn't install it correctly. Enter into cpan shell and run `install XML::Twig`.

Comment: Thanks @Brei. After installing as XML::Twig, i get a compilation error in Twig.Not sure what's going on. Thanks for your help again.
Use of uninitialized value in -f at /Library/Perl/5.12/XML/Twig.pm line 752.
Couldn't open :

Comment: @BalajiNatarajan: How are you executing the script? Run it like I pasted in my post (or post it here). `XML::Twig` dies in the `->parsefile()` function because argument is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Brei. I overlooked the trailing -. Now is the time for me to start learning Perl. Thanks again, your solution worked!!